# Need CSS coding for XML table

Tags: css, xml, css-tables

My problem is that I have to stylize an XML file into a table using CSS. I've tried everything and I still can't get it how I like it to be.

Below is my XML coding. Anyone who can help me find a solution to this headache.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="record.css" ?>

 <Record>

<data> 
<data-header> StudentId </data-header> 
<data-header> Surname </data-header> 
<data-header> Name </data-header> 
<data-header> Course </data-header> 
</data>

<data> 
<data-cell> 00123 </data-cell> 
<data-cell> Jack </data-cell>
<data-cell> Jim </data-cell> 
<data-cell> BSc </data-cell> 
</data>

<data> 
<data-cell> 00124 </data-cell> 
<data-cell> Jenny </data-cell>
<data-cell> Janet </data-cell> 
<data-cell> Diploma </data-cell>
</data>

 </Record>
```

This is my CSS (which is not the way I want it to be):

```
Record { 
    display:table; 
    font-size:14px; 
    margin:8px; 
    font-family: Verdana; display:block 
} 
data{ 
    display:block; 
    text-align:center; 
    border: 1px solid silver; 
    padding:10px; 
    background-color:whitesmoke; 
} 
data-cell,data-header { 
    display: table-cell; 
    border: solid 1px; 
}
```

This is what I want it to look like:

- The first line are 4 headers
- Everything should be centered (header and data under it)
- The cells should use all the space in the column
- Each column should be 25% of the total.

Comment: @BigRabbit

Record 

{

display:table;
font-size:14px; 
margin:8px; 
font-family: Verdana; 
display:block

}

data{
display:block; 
text-align:center;
border: 1px solid silver;
padding:10px; 
background-color:whitesmoke;
}

data-cell,data-header
{
display: table-cell; 
border: solid 1px;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Record { 
    display:table; 
    font-size:14px; 
    margin:8px; 
    font-family: Verdana; 
    width: 100%;
} 
data{ 
    display:table-row; 
    text-align:center; 
    border: 1px solid silver; 
    padding:10px; 
    background-color:whitesmoke; 
} 
data-cell,data-header { 
    display: table-cell; 
    border: solid 1px; 
    width: 25%;
}
```

And experiment with it here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/65dRu/)

You were using `block` instead of `table-row`. The rest you can control with `width`.

Comment: I've tried it and it works perfect. I thought twas the same as table row as all example I've seen on the web uses "block". Thanks for the help.